# Multiple htmls under one url

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a little game and I am connecting every page with buttons(I must use buttons no matter what), so I am creating multiple htmls, but I want all htmls to be published under one url and I want to know if it is possible?(if this is not possible can i make a multi page html so it seems like there are multiple htmls, but in reality there is only one?)

Comment: You're talking about a single page application (SPA). There are many ways and frameworks to create one. Your best bet is now to research for them and choose the one that fits you the best. There will be a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all your content in one HTML page, then use anchors to delimit and some simple CSS to hide/show content based on which anchor is clicked.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/lovetrivedi/hqnjW/

Alternatively if you use PHP you could have one index.php you could call the other HTML files with simple GET parameters, like `example.com/index.php?p=1`

Answer (score 0):

The URL is the resource locator, i.e. https://my-url.net. There you can publish multiple html files, but accessing these requires a URI resource identifier, i.e. https://my-url.net/my-first-html-page.html.

Because it sounds like, that you are in the beginning of this, I would suggest you to put all your htmls in one file in several `<div>` that are not visible by default. Your buttons then can control the visibility of each div on demand.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! you can do this. You must use javascript to do this. For that, it will require to create a button. The button will target the div element to show.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.mydiv {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunctiontwo()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV" class="mydiv">
This is my DIV element one.
</div>
<div id="myDIVtwo" class="mydiv">
This is my DIV element two.
</div>


<script>
var x;
var y;
function myFunction() {
   x = document.getElementById("myDIV");

    x.style.display = "block";

    y.style.display = "none";

}
function myFunctiontwo() {
  y = document.getElementById("myDIVtwo");
   y.style.display = "block";

   x.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```